# Is there any solution for git - error: bad signature without losing (non-committed) data

Tags: git, github

I was working on a branch and it was working fine. After some work, when I type `git status` this happens:

```
mac-mini:production_designs jithinraj$ git status
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Now I can't `commit` or do anything on my branch. Any solution for this **without losing my data that was not committed**?

Comment: Hi, did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git

Comment: @DurdenP Yes, but will it delete my unsaved data.?

Comment: I don't know. Anyway, I suggest to you to make a backup only of the involved files before.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**I fixed my issue without loosing my data -**

1. Deleted the `index` file manually.
2. After that, I used the command **`git reset --keep`** (you may need to delete `index.lock` file as well)
3. Then used the command `git status`*(it will take some time)* magically all my changed files were there for me to `commit`.

Thank you for your time guys. Really appreciate it.

Comment: The fear of losing changes is real. But this solution worked like a charm. Just for safety, first clone the project in a new repo. Then follow the above steps. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 11):

Try to reset your git.
it may be because of any index or file got corrupted.

Once I also faced the same problem.
Got fixed with below command:

```
rm -f .git/index


git reset .
```

I hope this resolve that issue.

Comment: But will it affect my unsaved data.?

Comment: do first:   git reset .  then check git status   you can see your data(file where you made changes). it won't removed unsaved data.

Comment: Are you sure? Will  `git reset . ` delete my data.?

Comment: it wasn't deleted any data for me..hope it won't delete for you.For your sake of convinance please do one thing. Do changes in some file in other code base. then do "git add filename" and after that do "git reset filename" still you have your data.

Comment: I got my solution using `git reset --keep` ty for your time, +1 for your efforts. :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers didn't work for me, [so I pulled an XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1597/). Hey, if it works, it works!

---

Step out of your repo folder

```
cd ..
```

Rename the original (broken folder)

```
mv folder folder_backup
```

Re-clone the repo

```
git clone <repo>
```

Move the (possibly changed) files back

```
cp -r folder_backup/* folder
```

Now you have a working repo again, because you recloned it, with your (possibly changed) files, that you copied back, so now you can commit/push those changes.