# How to resolve “Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt” when using Git-SVN

Tags: git, git-svn

i'm currently using git svn in one of my repo and when i do

```
git svn fetch
```

i got

```
Found possible branch point: coherent tag ref
Initializing parent: ok stuff

error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
command returned error: 128
```

Is ther a way to fix this ? It's a kind of an horrible repo. It take days to synch to that point, i dont want to start from begining :/.

I try the

```
rm .git/index
```

from [How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git) but there is no such file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to delete the "index" in the refs svn folder (from the root repo):

```
rm .git/svn/refs/{path/to/incriminated/ref}/index
```

Then my

```
git svn fetch
```

worked again.

Comment: Nice, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to spot the .git folder manually by going into your repository?   you can try running below command to possibly get more information?

```
git fsck --full
```

Comment: Just giive me an ok result. But i finally found how to do.

Comment: is my solution acceptable? can you please post your solution as well so that it helps others?

Comment: I already did. Cannot accept my answer atm, Will do it as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

just try to rename `your_project/.git/index` file

Answer (score 0):

I had another `.git` folder in my subfolder, therefore, causing the error. I would remove the `.git` subfolder and then remove the cached folder you were looking to commit: `git rm --cached subfoldername`