# Git index file corrupt

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gitlab-ci

I have a project with a gitlab CI for my school project for around 3 months now and never had an issue. But, yesterday morning when I wanted to commit my new code changes and push it to my Gitlab. This worked completely fine, however my CI keeps failing:

[image: This is the error message]

In text:

```
1 Running with gitlab-runner 13.9.0 (2ebc4dc4)
2 on 
3 Preparing the "shell" executor
4 Using Shell executor...
6 Preparing environment
7 Running on
9 Getting source from Git repository
10 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
11 Reinitialized existing Git repository in
12 Checking out 437a9a83 as master... 
13 error: bad signature 0x00000000
14 fatal: index file corrupt 
16 Cleaning up file based variables
18 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

didn't notice my branch failed so I also merged this with

I was working in a separate branch and didn't notice my branch failed, so I also merged this with my main branch so `main` isn't working as well.

Comment: This is an internal error happening on whatever machine is running the gitlab pipeline. It indicates either failing hardware, or improperly configured software, there. It's not something you can fix on your own machine unless your own machine *is* the gitlab pipeline machine.

Comment: If your machine *is* the pipeline runner, check for any disk failures, and make sure you do not put any Git repositories on any networked or shared drives or synced (iCloud, Dropbox, Google, etc) drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 3290](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3290)

> The Git index file got corrupted causing the build to fail and the runner is not able to recover.
> It should be able to handle this by deleting the index file and resetting the repo

As in "[How to resolve “Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt” when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115956/6309)"

See if the issue persists in a second GitLab pipeline, created for testing, in order to force a new clone of the same repository.