# How to fix git corrupted index without losing git history?

Tags: git, visual-studio

My computer suddenly restarted just after I commited my last change, and when I was back it no longer could bring the git for my repo. I checked git files all of files is there but I get different errors when I use git bash commands.

(Opening repositories:
D:\Projects\Engine\Engine
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: bad signature 0x00000000
fatal: index file corrupt)

I did this but it totally removed all of my history and put me back on just having to add a new source control git, but I want to be able to restore the history and not lose my history cause all old commit files are there and havent touched by anything for some time.
[How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git?rq=1)

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

This deleted all of my history and started a new git.
I had backups for my .git folder before I do this command so now it back to that error again.

[.git folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff13J.jpg)

[Visual Studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nssj2.jpg)

[commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4IUS.jpg)

After running command: ("git fsck") these are all errors:
[All git errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6go0g.jpg)

(Please if possible for instant respond from me email me or message me in discord, cause I've tried a lot of things but they didnt work, then we can apply the final answer to the post. Thanks for helping me.
shahroozleon01@gmail.com/SHAHROOZ#2185)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "Error: bad index – Fatal: index file corrupt" when using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115854/how-to-resolve-error-bad-index-fatal-index-file-corrupt-when-using-git)

Comment: @prakashsellathurai I've already said that it didnt work, it just deleted my git and made a new one, and I lost all of my git history and everything.

Comment: Do other commands, which shouldn't depend on the index, work ? For example : can you inspect the history of your repo, with a GUI or `git log --oneline --graph` ?

Comment: @LeGEC
Fatal: your current branch appears to be broken.

Comment: Ok, so you have some other files which aren't ok. What is the cont of `cat .git/HEAD` ?

Comment: @LeGEC ref:/ refs/heads/master

Comment: Ok, that's a regular content. To assess the state of that local clone : run `git fsck`. To assess how much work is at risk : do you have other clones of that repo ?

Comment: @LeGEC ok, dude can we chat it seems stackover is not happy with long comments.
my discrod if you have anything lese let me know thanks 
SHAHROOZ#2185

Comment: @LeGEC
it says this
[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/677604453171462214/884044654776049744/Screenshot_2021-09-05_162653.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your master ref and its log, and the HEAD ref log, have been torched by an ill-timed restart, but it's not clear yet whether anything else got damaged. Fortunately, it's not so very hard to recover this stuff, because while Git might not be bulletproof, it is near-as-dammit unkillable with proper care.  Sometimes you just have to play combat medic if you're going to take it in to a war zone.

So:

```
rm .git/refs/heads/master       # remove damaged ancillary pointers and logs
rm .git/logs/HEAD               # .
rm .git/logs/refs/heads/master  # .
rm .git/index                   # .
                                # find the recently-added stuff:
find .git/objects/?? -ctime -2 -type f -exec ls -t {} +|awk -F/ '{print $3$4}' \
| git cat-file --batch-check
```

to show you everything you added to the repo in the last couple days, most recent first. The most recent commit (the first one it lists) is very likely to be the one you made; with any luck you'll be able to

```
git reset -q $thatsha
git update-index --refresh
git checkout -b master
```

and you'll be back in business, but if that doesn't work post the *text* transcript of what happened instead and we can continue the learn-by-doing.

Comment: Thanks for you help dude, it didnt report any error and it opened the git But unfortunately it didnt show up any commit or history, but all of my commit files are still in .git\objects folder, but the action was as same as deleting whole git and made anew.

Comment: ff1a61877255a2f5c229eb1254923a78820f1d3f commit 173
6b8d27fc62cfa29078afd07ef05c33c696d3ab35 commit 173
a9f19d3c6830fb1d2c20b9259eff3b249bb667d6 commit 273
dbff4f1ab6c1747d17d6ad54d95c76f1049664eb tree 151
7a9bb915c095332b0f78eb71f7294f43f0ba3b05 tree 9802
...
shows this after the "find .git/objects..." command.

Comment: So, `git checkout -b master ff1a61877255a2f5c229eb1254923a78820f1d3f` says what?

Comment: ```git checkout -b master ff1a61877255a2f5c229eb1254923a78820f1d3f``` says fatal reference is not a tree and
```git checkout -b master $thatsha``` says switched to a new branch 'master'
but I ran checkout -b master ff1a/ after $thatsha
should I run that first?

Comment: Okay, `git cat-file -p ff1a618` should complain that the object is corrupt, the previous added commit is 6b8d27f, try `git checkout -B master 6b8d27fc62cfa29078afd07ef05c33c696d3ab35`, notice the caps b here I'm just overriding whatever's there now.

Comment: Did the find really list three commits one afer another? Don't be afraid to edit the complete readout (or say the first ten lines,pipe it through `head`) into your question body.

Comment: it didnt fit into a comment @jthill
[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/677604453171462214/884192943831932968/Screenshot_2021-09-06_021547.jpg)

Comment: ```git checkout -B master 6b8d27fc62cfa29078afd07ef05c33c696d3ab35```
says reference is not a tree.

Comment: Sometime in here all the old hands here are going to want to get you onto a toolkit that doesn't treat text like an alien creature to be kept behind glass.  The text at that link isn't ***at all*** what you pasted in to the comment. Hunt up how to pipe command output to the clipboard, and for now try using 1d693533 for the sha since that's what your picture shows being listed first.

Comment: it says 
```error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
``` almost half of my files then ```aborting```

Comment: and VS now again shows no old history, just the one I now have to create to show the master branch.
its all gone again.
btw I think it showed all of my files there not half of them.

Comment: Okay, this is actually good. `git reset -q 1d6935ee; git update-index --refresh; git checkout -b master; git status` (yah I typoed transcribing from your picture before) and you're almost all the way home. Ignore what VS is telling you, it's a frontend that can't interpret what it's seeing, we'll deal with it later.

Comment: Oh gosh, I lost the the track can you please again tell me these step by step in which order I should run them i'm lost. sorry
After first part of your post (```rm .git/refs/heads/master       # remove damaged ancillary pointers and logs
rm .git/logs/HEAD               # .
rm .git/logs/refs/heads/master  # .
rm .git/index                   # .
                                # find the recently-added stuff:
find .git/objects/?? -ctime -2 -type f -exec ls -t {} +|awk -F/ '{print $3$4}' \
| git cat-file --batch-check```) what next?

Comment: Im doing it again on a untouched .git folder by any command but still like the first place corrupt.
[link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/677604453171462214/884202453111803935/Screenshot_2021-09-06_025438.jpg).
if you only could come and chat it would be much easier for me.

Comment: All the noise and confusion here is due to you not showing the actual evidence you're looking at. Once you showed that, it was easy. The first commit it showed you was 1d6935ee, do the `git reset -q 1d6935ee` etc sequence above.

Comment: OMG it worked, thanks soooo much youre a legend bro. I reallllllly appreciate that. THAT WAS AWESOME.

Comment: btw if you want to update your answer post do it then we accept your answer.
Again I am REALLY grateful.

Comment: Gotta say, I appreciate the kind words. Thanks back atcha.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, Git's index / cache is largely a temporary data structure that can be rebuilt.  (When you do this, you lose any staging work you've done, but usually that's minor.)  The `rm -f .git/index` and `git reset` that you tried are the way to do this rebuild.

Unfortunately, you have significantly worse damage to your repository.  In particular, the `refs/heads/master` file in your repository is corrupt.  While you *can* remove that file, or put a valid hash ID in it (if you can find a valid commit hash ID), this may well leave various other problems.  Ideally, you might find the correct *last* commit and put that hash ID into the file.

This may, or may not, still leave further problems, but at this point `git reset` can work (it can't until you fix the `refs/heads/master` issue) and then `git fsck` can get further along.

Your best bet by far is to recover everything from some other up-to-date clone, but if you don't have any other up-to-date clone, that option is lost.  Depending on what other damage, if any, there is in *this* clone, it may or may not be possible to repair.

Comment: I've been told the same by others too. :_(

Comment: ff1a61877255a2f5c229eb1254923a78820f1d3f commit

-is this the commit hash you were talking about?

Comment: I don't know - commit hashes are impossible to predict without knowing the contents.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION** (*At least for me*)

1. Clone the project in a new folder (*as a backup just to be on a safe side*)
2. Delete `.git/index` and `.git/index.lock` (if present)
3. Run `git reset --keep` from the root of the project's repo in question

And voila!

Comment: thank you for your attention and answer.