# git all the file marked as conflict

Tags: git, merge

I am new to GIT (from SVN). When I make a merge, all the file is set as conflicted (not only the lines where there is really a conflict).
This should come from a "end of line" problem between me (Windows) and my partner (Mac) but how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[man page for git-attributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Set the proper attributes to tell Git to normalize line endings.

Comment: Amber is pointing you to the right place. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-handling-strategy-with-git for a discussion here on SO concerning CRLF.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you must enable the `core.autocrlf` config option, see e.g. [this document](http://help.github.com/dealing-with-lineendings/) and the manual pages for [git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and [gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). If conflicts occurred then the merge commit shouldn't have been made, and you should be able to revert the partial merge with [git reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).