# GIT: How to get rid of the annoying CRLF message on msysgit (windows)?

Tags: git, newline, git-gui, core.autocrlf

Practically everytime I stage a textfile (that's most of em), I get the message from git gui (I use msysgit) that It replaced (or is about to) line endings with CRLF's. Obviously I want that (and there's a setting for it huraah), but I don't want the annoying message popped up all the time!

Any way to keep the setting, but turn off/disable the popup message?

I have no idea how this works with GIT on the commandline, but I like msysgit's staging process :) so I'd rather not change to bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line just prints a message, and that's it.

I don't think that the message box can be disabled, unfortunately...

Answer (score 6):

One thing you could do, is setting the appropriate setting in the repo-config. The option `core.autocrlf` will do these things:

1. All text-files will be stored with `LF` line-endings.
2. When reading from disk, `CRLF` is converted to `LF`
3. When writing to disk, `LF` is converted to `CRLF`

You can set this option in git-shell

```
$ cd path/to/repo
$ git config core.autocrlf true
```

And then, delete any file but the `.git` folder itself from the repo and run

```
$ git reset --hard
$ git commit -am "Line endings fixed."
```

To fix he line endings.

PS: There is a small chance, that binary files are accidentially threated as text files and may be corrupted, then you have to read the manual or just ask here.

Comment: BTW, maybe you set `core.autocrlf` to some strange value, maybe post your config.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using msysgit, I will assume `core.autocrlf` is set to tru (the default setting in msysgit installation)

You could try setting [`core.safecrlf`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to false, and see if that has any influence on this kind of message.

```
git config core.safecrlf false
```

You can also try version a [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file and set a:

```
*        eol=crlf
```

directive to see if that explicit text attribute has any bearing on this warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make sure: `core.autocrlf=false`.

I don't really know msysgit, but after a little searching, I found a couple of related [msysgit](http://www.mail-archive.com/msysgit@googlegroups.com/msg00658.html) / [threads](http://groups.google.com/group/msysgit/msg/7844bb49060e7981?pli=1).
Also see a related SO Q: [What's the best CRLF handling strategy with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-handling-strategy-with-git).

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use CRLF as line endings in your text editor, and git will have nothing to warn you about. (Execpt maybe once, if the pulled file doesn't have CRLF line endings).