# Does GIT does the CRLF/LF conversion during commit or checkout(vi)?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf, git-commit

I have a doubt now, does Git does the CRLF conversion during a commit or during a `vi` of the file?

Let’s say I have some files in Windows with CRLF (not a Git repo), when I sync these files to a UNIX Git repo and do git add/commit with `autocrlf true` enabled, will these files get the conversion from CRLF to LF?

Or does it do the conversion of these files only when I `vi` these files and commit it again?

---

The second doubt is, what should be the `autocrlf` and `safecrlf` setting in both Unix and Windows Git clones if my parent repository exists in Unix and need LF alone. Should I use global setting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlftrue-in-git

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in [issue 449](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=449):

> `svn:eol-style` (**just like `core.autocrl`f**) is a **mechanism that happens on checkout and commit**.

As for the value of that setting, on both sides (Windows/Unix), [I always set it to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlftrue-in-git) (in a [global setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063618/unable-to-understand-how-gits-difftool-configs-are-set/1063646#1063646)), as [jleedev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19750/jleedev) comments on your question.
[Same for `safecrl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841140/git-how-to-get-rid-of-the-annoying-crlf-message-on-msysgit-windows/3841198#3841198).