# git behavior on line ending (CR/LF) handling (.gitattribute)

Tags: git

I am handling a C++/C repository, for both Windows and Linux environments.  In fact, the editor on Windows and Linux can accept textfile with either CR/LF or LF ending (even mixed mode).  The problem is that, the user may create new .cpp, .h files with their native line ending format (CR/LF, or just LF).  What is the best settings for .gitattributes?

To describe the problem is detail, I have an assumption, and want to meet the following requirements:

> The Assumption: I don't care if a checkout gets CR/LF or LF ending
>   style, since modern editors can handle both, either on Windows or
>   Un*x.
>
> Requirement 1. If two versions of files differs only in their line
>   endings styles, the system (meaning git client, git database, etc..)
>   shall regard them as the same version.  Thus git diff should show no
>   difference, git merge won't need to do anything... etc..
>
> Requirement 2. The files in the working directory shall be kept as is.
>   Even some of the files may be in DOS-style, and some of the files in
>   Unix-style.  (For example, on Windows, some files are edited by VIM
>   under cygwin, which has Unix-style, and some uses native windows
>   editor, which results in DOS-style).  i.e. In the working directory,
>   the files' ending style shall not be changed due to any git
>   transaction (commit, merge, etc ...) [Oh, I can accept when a merge
>   occurs, files may be changed.]

In addition, I found this bug? in git: (see the following transactions)

```
bash (master) $ git status
# On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean)

bash (master) $ file a.c
a.c: C source, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

bash (master) $ dos2unix a.c
dos2unix: converting file a.c to Unix format ...

bash (master) $ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   a.c
# no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

bash (master) $ git add a.c
bash (master) $ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

As you can see in the transaction, when the line ending style changes, `git status` does not realize that the changes are merely the line endings, and reports the modification of `a.c`.  Though after `git add a.c`, the status was corrected.  My .gitattributes force all .c and .h to use `lf` only:

```
bash (master) $ cat .gitattributes
*    text=auto

*.c  text eol=lf
*.C  text eol=lf
*.cpp  text eol=lf
*.CPP  text eol=lf
*.h  text eol=lf
*.H  text eol=lf
*.hpp  text eol=lf
*.HPP  text eol=lf

*.pro  text eol=crlf
```

Could anyone show me how to avoid it, or is it a bug? (or just an as-is behavior, not a bug, since asking `git status` to sense the line end changes requires a `diff` which is costly?)?

I have read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888098/does-git-does-the-crlf-lf-conversion-during-commit-or-checkoutvi), yet it does not answer me if the files in working directories will be changed or not.  And I have searched many links and found some suggestions for a pure system like Linux or Windows, but can anyone have suggestions for a combined system, like Windows + Cygwin on a same system?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answer only this part of the question:

> `git diff` should show no difference for files differing only in line-ending style...

1. The `diff` command has a `--strip-trailing-cr` option that ignores LF vs CRLF distinctions
2. git allows an external diff command. So we make a `difficr` (diff-ignore-cr) command thus:

   ```
   $ cat difficr
   #! /bin/sh
   diff --strip-trailing-cr "$2" "$5"
   ```

The `$2` and `$5` are because those are the actual file args.
See the GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF in the main git 
[man-page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/).

And setup git config:

```
    $  git config --global diff.external "/path/to/difficr"
```

Now you should find that `git diff`s ignore LF vs CRLF distinctions.

[At least my experiments show it to do so]