# why git is considering the whole file changed while just a part of it is changed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I'm facing a strange situation with `git` . I just have edited several lines in a long file but then when I went to commit changes ,I saw that git just highlighted the whole file content with a red color . what is wrong ?

I'm using git's windows GUI

Edit : one thing I remember now is that I added .csproj to the gitignore list in last commit . does this has any effect on this ?

Update : the problem as friends suggested was from line ending . I solved it using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273)

Comment: That's strange, are you sure you have committed the contents of that file previously? What does `git diff` tell you? Haven't you changed to a branch where you don't have that specific file?

Comment: @rlegendi : one thing I just remember is that I added .csproj to gitignore in last commit . that is the problem , right ?

Comment: Give output of your git status.

Comment: Also, could your text editor be using the wrong line ending? Is it potentially using the line ending that causes git to think your entire file is one long line?

Comment: As others have suggested, this sounds very much like a line ending issue: what is `core.autocrlf` set to (`git config core.autocrlf`) and what editor did you use to change the file?

Comment: @MarkLongair : I'm using VS 2010 , core.autocrlf is set to true ,

Comment: @MarkLongair : thank you mark , it was as you said . solved now

Comment: You should write up the answer and answer your own question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was because of **line ending** .

`git config core.autocrlf` was set to **true** . I used solutions mentioned in this 2 posts

[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)

[Trying to fix line-endings with git filter-branch, but having no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273)

and set it as **false** . and it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem in Visual Studio 2015 (vs2015) on Windows with files that we had edited but un-done all edits.

The only thing I would add to the other answer and what we ended up doing is to try editing the **.gitattributes** at the root of your solution by commenting out

```
* text=auto
```

to be

```
#* text=auto
```

According to [this](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#per-repository-settings) article, this entry overrides the git config so even if you remove the other entry in the git config the problem could still occur.

Commenting the .gitattributes removed the fake edits and uncommenting it added the fake edits back in for us.

Where this answer originally came from: [Files showing as modified directly after git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone)