# Git show, shows all files as changed after fresh clone

Tags: git

As the question says, after I do a fresh clone of a repo, a git show, shows a lot of files as changed, but I haven't yet touched any of the files. A git diff gives nothing.

I need to make changes and see the changes using a git show, but only my own changes. The git show currently isn't letting me do this.

I checked out the following question, but I don't have a .gitattributes file.

[Files showing as modified directly after git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone)

---

EDIT : Using git on linux.

Comment: first of all, to check out if files have changed, you use `git status`, not `git show` (the latter is for viewing details of already-made commits). second, changed-but-not-changed files usually are caused by line-ending issues. Do you have EOL-conversion enabled? (are you using Windows?)

Comment: git status returns a "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" and still git show returns a lot of files that seem to have changed.

Comment: as I said, `git show` tells you what changed in a commit. If a lot of files changed in the last commit (changes between `HEAD` and `HEAD^`), then it will show a lot of stuff. `git show` will not tell you any differences between your working tree and a commit; that's what `git diff` is for

Comment: How do I get HEAD and HEAD^ in sync?

Comment: `HEAD^` is the parent commit of `HEAD` -- you can't get them in sync (or if you do, you have an empty commit, which usually you don't want)

Comment: I need to generate a patch using git show (there's a required format they want the patch in), and so I can't have the older changes in my patch. Is there no work around? I'm guessing the empty commit will cause trouble the next time I pull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show` is used to show all the changes of between HEAD and HEAD~1.

I think what you are looking for is `git diff --cached`. (Assuming you have already staged your changes using `git add`)