# Github for Mac not showing code comparison

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

My github client for mac stopped showing code comparison when working with my github repos- it just shows the entire file content as deleted (in red with the "-" sign).
I tried re-installing the app and re-configuring my repo but it didn't solve it.

The strange thing is that somehow the problem happens only in the combination of the mac client with the github repository:

- The same Github for Mac does show diff correctly against a different git repository (Heroku)
- The git command-line does show diff correctly for this Github repository

Only the combination of the mac client with that specific githuv repository doesn't work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-cloning the repo from GitHub finally solved it

**Edit:** the root cause for the problem was that in a sub-directory inside the repo, I had another git repo, pointing to Heroku. For some reason it doesn't get along together in the Mac client

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on Mac OS and that repository has been created using a different operating system it might be the problem presented here: [Files showing as modified directly after git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone)

Comment: Thanks - I tried everything suggested there with no success. Also, in my case git diff works correctly so I suspect it's a different situation