# Git status shows "modified" files when I checkout a new branch

Tags: git, branch, status, git-checkout

I do a clone of my repo

```
git clone user@githost:repo
```

I get master branch. Now I checkout a remote branch

```
git checkout branch_name
```

now my git status shows 150+ files modified, why?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the git status output?

Comment: related to difference in new lines?  Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone

Comment: `11:22 $ git st               
On branch branch_name              
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/branch_name'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxofile.xml
        modified:   xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxofile.xml/src/main/java/com/****.java`
        150+ of these

Comment: most probably file permission/mode changes you can ignore that using     

git config core.fileMode false

Comment: Here is my git config `[core]
    autocrlf = false
    fileMode = false` I removed my directory and re-did steps 1 and 2 above, still see the files modified