# Immediately after git clone, I see "Changes not staged for commit" and git diff shows changes

Tags: git, github

I'm getting a really weird behaviour when cloning a repo that a developer friend is working on. Immediately after a `git clone` I get a list of 15 different `modified` files when checking `git status`.

When I do `git diff`, I see actual changes to the code.

```
-$this->title = 'Create Itemtype';
+$this->title = 'Create item type';
```

```
-    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
-
     <?= $this->render('_form', [
```

The result of `git status` is as follows:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   backend/models/FeaturegroupItem.php
modified:   backend/models/FeaturegroupItemSearch.php
modified:   backend/models/VendorItemquestionansweroption.php
modified:   backend/models/VendorItemquestionansweroptionSearch.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/Itemtype/_form.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/Itemtype/create.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/Itemtype/index.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/Itemtype/update.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/vendorItemquestionansweroption/_form.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/vendorItemquestionansweroption/_search.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/vendorItemquestionansweroption/create.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/vendorItemquestionansweroption/index.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/vendorItemquestionansweroption/update.php
modified:   backend/modules/admin/views/vendorItemquestionansweroption/view.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Add the output of git status to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Files showing as modified directly after git clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone)

Comment: Is this reproducable? Can you post the exact steps?

Comment: @IgalS. I've checked that post, I have actual code differences.

Comment: @mu無 I have added the output

Comment: @1615903 It's reproducable. There are no steps other than cloning from a Github private repository