# git clone modifies file type and content in a non-reproducible way

Tags: git, text, version-control, character-encoding, bitbucket

I am experiencing a strange behavior of git clone -- some of the files in a git repository, hosted on bitbucket, are modified right after git clone. This problem looks similar to the one reported in the following questions,

- [Files showing as modified directly after git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5009096/883431)
- [Git status shows files as changed even though contents are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5787937/883431)

but does not look quite the same. In my case, only a couple of files out of about two thousands are modified. I detected the modification by `git status` right after `git clone`. These modified files were originally text files with ascii encoding, but after cloning they were regarded as a binary file, as the `file` command showed:

```
norio@machine-original $ file -bi t_pot_2e_fft002.f90
text/plain; charset=us-ascii

norio@machine-new $ file -bi t_pot_2e_fft002.f90
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

where `t_pot_2e_fft002.f90` is a file that was found to be modified.

In these modified files, a few but not all of commas `,`, white spaces , and underscores `_` were replaced with some non-ASCII characters, but I can still read most part of the file by the `less` command or emacs.

I repeated cloning 6 times into a different local directories, and I saw the modification 2 times. In the other 4 times, there was no modification. In the 2 cases in which files were modified, the files modified were different from one case to another.

I worked on repositories on `machine-original` and `machine-original2` (to which I do not have access any more) pushing to and fetching from a remote repository on bitbucket. Now I am cloning this repository on bitbucket to `machine-new`. The version of git is `1.9.1` on `machine-original` and `2.14.1` on `machine-new`. (Edit: `machine-original` runs ubuntu 14.04 and `machine-new` runs ubuntu 17.10.)

I had `core.filemode=true` on `machine-original` until I realize this problem. Then, I changed it to false, but I do not know how to propagate the effect to remote repository -- I did `git push`, but only got `Everything up-to-date`.

I do not have the `.gitattributes` file mentioned in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363472/883431) to one of the questions above.

Can anyone explain why these non-reproducible modifications are made upon cloning? Is it safe to keep using a cloned repository if no modification was detected by `git status` right after `git clone`?

Comment: Does machine-new and machine-original have different OS or the same OS? Usually for different OS, they encoding file with different manners.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. machine-original is ubuntu 14.04 and machine-new is ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Does the output for the command `hexdump -bc t_pot_2e_fft002.f90` same or not when run the command in the two machine separately?

Comment: The outputs are different.

Comment: Which file system are you using?

Comment: ext4 on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Since the output `hexdump -bc t_pot_2e_fft002.f90` from the separate machines are different, that means the encodings are different. Maybe when the file pushed from a different machine with a kind of encoding, and when you clone the repo to another machine, it will encoding with a different way.

More details about encodings, you can also refer [Dealing with inconsistent or corrupt character encodings](http://www.martinaulbach.net/linux/command-line-magic/41-dealing-with-inconsistent-or-corrupt-character-encodings).

When you set `core.filemode` as `false`, you actually didn’t change the file but "ignore the original encoding".  And for your situation, you’d better set `core.filemode` as `false`:

> **core.fileMode**
>
> Tells Git if the executable bit of files in the working
> tree is to be honored.
>
> Some filesystems lose the executable bit when a file that is marked as
> executable is checked out, or checks out a non-executable file with
> executable bit on. git-clone[1](http://www.martinaulbach.net/linux/command-line-magic/41-dealing-with-inconsistent-or-corrupt-character-encodings) or git-init[1](http://www.martinaulbach.net/linux/command-line-magic/41-dealing-with-inconsistent-or-corrupt-character-encodings) probe the filesystem to
> see if it handles the executable bit correctly and this variable is
> automatically set as necessary.
>
> A repository, however, may be on a filesystem that handles the
> filemode correctly, and this variable is set to true when created, but
> later may be made accessible from another environment that loses the
> filemode (e.g. exporting ext4 via CIFS mount, visiting a Cygwin
> created repository with Git for Windows or Eclipse). In such a case it
> may be necessary to set this variable to false. See
> git-update-index[1](http://www.martinaulbach.net/linux/command-line-magic/41-dealing-with-inconsistent-or-corrupt-character-encodings).
>
> The default is true (when core.filemode is not specified in the config
> file).

More details, you can refer [core.fileMode](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corefileMode).