# File show as modified after git clone and this file not exist

Tags: git

I have tried git checkout -- . many times but it seems not to do anything.
And i use all from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-git-clone)

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   File.ini

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

ls -al:
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   867 15 nov 00:52 File_1.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   399 15 nov 00:52 File_2.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   900 15 nov 00:52 File_3.ini
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   168 15 nov 01:00 file.ini

git config --list --show-origin:
file:.git/config    core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config    core.autoclrf=false
file:.git/config    core.filemode=true
file:.git/config    core.bare=false
file:.git/config    core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config    core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config    core.precomposeunicode=true
file:.git/config    remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
file:.git/config    branch.master.remote=origin
file:.git/config    branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: What's your operating system?  Are you on a shared drive of some type?  Have you changed any git configuration?  What's the output of `git output --list --show-origin`?

Comment: *git reset —hard* would remove all uncommitted changes

Comment: after git reset --hard git status say "modified:   file.ini" again reset --hard "modified:   File.ini"

Comment: @EdwardThomson macos, no git configurations changed. git output --list --show-origin :: git: 'output' is not a git command.

Comment: Sorry; I meant `git config --list --show-origin`.  (Apologies.)

Comment: @EdwardThomson       `file:.git/config core.repositoryformatversion=0`
`file:.git/config core.autoclrf=false`
`file:.git/config core.filemode=true`
`file:.git/config core.bare=false`
`file:.git/config core.logallrefupdates=true`
`file:.git/config core.ignorecase=true`
`file:.git/config core.precomposeunicode=true`
`file:.git/config remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`
`file:.git/config branch.master.remote=origin`
`file:.git/config branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master`

Comment: what does `git diff` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> modified:   File.ini
> -rw-r--r-- 1 user staff 168 15 nov 01:00 file.ini
> ```

That looks like a case issue: `File.ini` vs. `file.ini`

One way would be for your [MacOs volume disk to be "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)" in "Format".](https://coderwall.com/p/mgi8ja/case-sensitive-git-in-mac-os-x-like-a-pro)

Another would be [`git config core.ignorecase false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688308/6309), or [`git mv file.ini File.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979063/6309)

Comment: Thank you. But this command `git config core.ignorecase false` doesn't work  and `mv` is the last i do. I'll try first way maybe helps.

Comment: Thanks! Create volume disk with Case-sensitive, Journaled helped me!

Comment: Cygwin also seems to have this issue. Not clear if there is a fix in that case.

Comment: @personal_cloud Not clear indeed. Since git bash (packaged with Git For windows) or WSL, I do not use Cygwin since quite a long time ago.