# Committed changes are not reflecting actual changes in GIT using PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

This happens sometimes or for some files, not all, in case I make small changes to a file, instead of showing that small portion as a change, git takes as the whole file is updated, as if all the lines are removed and rewritten.

For example of the following changes:

[image]

git shows the changes like this:

[image]

As we can see the whole file is changed.

Comment: Maybe a line ending issue, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009096/files-showing-as-modified-directly-after-a-git-clone)?

Comment: @kowsky That does not fix the issue.

Comment: Check & adjust accordingly line separators at File | Settings | Editor | Code Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to edit editorconfig and File | Settings | Editor | Code Style |  Line separators.