# Apache PredictionIO - Docker run failed

Tags: docker, predictionio

I have been trying http://predictionio.apache.org/install/install-docker/ this tutorial. I have successfully built Docker image however when I try to run `docker run` i get the `Can't open /etc/predictionio/pio-env.sh` error.

1. `docker build -t predictionio/pio pio`
2. `docker run -ti predictionio/pio`

PS: If I comment out the last line `CMD ["sh", "/usr/bin/pio_run"]` I can build and run docker image successfully. I can open the file too from docker bash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to grant permissions to execute this file. add the following line at the end of your Dockerfile

```
RUN chmod +x pio_run.sh
```

also, you might need to change CMD to ENTRYPOINT like following:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/bin/pio_run.sh"]
```

Comment: I have added EXEUTE. No luck.
I will try the `ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/bin/pio_run.sh"]`

Comment: Same result... :(

Comment: @biligunb What's your WORKDIR? It seems that it can't find that script in /usr/bin. make sure it is there . you can run 
  cd  /usr/bin&&ls to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Your output states you are running Windows. Did you use the default command prompt or did you use docker terminal? I had the same error messages in the past on Windows but mysteriously it disappeared after trying the tutorial again. I am not sure what I did different except I might possibly used docker instead of the default command prompt...

Could you also try using docker-compose instead of plain docker commands as described in the tutorial?

Ensure your storage (Postgres, MySQL or ElasticSearch) is running before starting PIO as well.

Comment: Yes. Win 10 Pro edition.  
I am using command prompt `CMD`  
And i tried the `docker-compose` first to no avail.  
Then i tried to login to bash and run from the docker.

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved it on my machine.

When you cloned repository on Windows, git converted end of line symbols from Unix-style (\n) to Windows style (\r\n).

You need to open file `C:\wherever-you-cloned-pio-repository\predictionio\docker\pio\pio_run` and change it back (for e.g. using Visual Studio Code, or Notepad++). Then you need to rebuild the image and it should work.

Also for the future you may want to disable automatic conversion [Disable git EOL Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822650/disable-git-eol-conversions)