# Unable to use LF files under Windows

Tags: git, eol

I'm developing under Windows. I'm using software which uses LF endings even under Windows (e.g. XILINX ISE for FPGAs) I'm not talking about UNIX here. I can't find a setting which tells GIT to just leave my line endings alone. Whatever i do, either i end with CRLF in the file OR i get idiotic errors like "LF would be replaced by CRLF" which blocks my commits.

I've tried various combinations of eol, autocrlf, safecrlf, ...

Nothing seems to just switch OFF everything EOL related.

What am i missing?

Many Thanks in advance

Carsten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable git EOL Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822650/disable-git-eol-conversions)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try the suggestions in the post.