# Run shell script in WSL with \r\n

Tags: bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Python project which is a bunch of Docker containers and terraform scripts. My workstation is Windows 10 so I have installed Ubuntu in WSL to develop it. The problem I am facing is there are a lot of shell scripts (.sh) that I need to run as the build process. In Git it always checks out the files as Windows style and commit files as Unix Style. As a result, the Ubuntu bash shell does not like these shell scripts and I have to run dos2unix before running a file. Is there a one liner that allows me to run these scripts without modifying them?

Comment: Can you fix up whatever git client you are using to preserve line-ends on checkout? One easier option might be to use git on WSL command line (it's what I do).

Answer (score 0):

If the scripts don't call another script you could

```
tr "\r\n" "\n" script.sh | bash
```

But in the other case I think you need to change your repository config to tell git to don't convert files with .sh extension. Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461324/5032541

If you want to change git configuration to remove auto conversion, take a look on [official documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings). But it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem imo is checking in the wrong file endings into git.

An easy way to fix all shell scripts at once is:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh" -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

It will recursively find all files with the .sh extension and perform dos2unix on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting your git repo to checkout linux style rather than windows line endings.

I do a lot of node/docker/linux work but have a windows 10 laptop, this is what I have done.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

See [this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace) for some more details. This way you dont need to continuously run scripts to make sure you have the correct line endings. Also a good thing to do is set you editor to default to linux line endings.