# git clone comes with edited files

Tags: linux, git, github

When I clone a project, I did `git status` right away and some files appear edited.
I check with `git diff .` and all edited files have the same message: "**warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF**".
I didn't even open any files.
`git checkout .` didn't work.
How is this possible?

Comment: You are on a Linux machine, are you not? (It's hard to tell but you do have [tag:linux] in your tags, which isn't really appropriate here but is a clue nonetheless.)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux new line mark it is `\n`, and on Windows it is `\r\n`, so it looks like when you clone a repository, the operating system changes `\r\n` to `\n` and you see the difference

Comment: ok, but on my colleagues' computer it doesn't happen

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822650/disable-git-eol-conversions