# Android Studio Open Project in Ubuntu previously on Windows says every file is changed

Tags: android, git, ubuntu, android-studio

I was previously working on `Android Studio 2.1.3` on `Windows 10`. Now I have migrated to `Ubuntu 16.04`. When I opened my project from the `NTFS` drive in Ubuntu Android Studio, It says each and every file is changed in `git`.

If I check the changed content, it says files are identical. When I tried to check from the external git client, it shows all lines as (-) and same content as (+). I don't understand why this had happened.

Do this has something with the end line character? What can I do now so that it can only show the changed content?

NOTE: This can be identified as a duplicate as for general scenario of line endings in any git repo. But, for specifically Android Studio this can be solved as per my answer.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "Android studio says and every file is changed in git"?

Comment: While commiting in Android Studio, it lists all the files..

Comment: This happens because in Windows the file had CRLF ending and in Ubuntu it has LF. Therefore it shows the file is changed.

Comment: How can I undo that? It will change my git history

Comment: Project is still on NTFS partition

Comment: Check my answer, and there is a much more detailed explanation on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this for Android Studio this 2 articles from the **IntelliJ** website, helped me.

1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/handling-lf-and-crlf-line-endings.html

2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-line-separators.html

This is what I did to solve it:

Open Terminal and type: `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

Set the default line endings:

- In Settings, click Code Style.
- From the Line separator (for new files) drop-down list, select the desired line separator style: **Windows**

Change the line separator of the files you have changed/created:

- Re-Open the files you have created in Ubuntu Android Studio
- From the status-bar click on the `LF` (if it is LF) and change it to `CRLF`.
- Do this for every file which is in LF (files you have created in Ubuntu Android Studio)

Now, restart Android Studio, And try to commit. You wont see all the files there. If you still see all files,  Unstage all files from any external git client and then re-start Android Studio and try to commit. Now, you will see only modified files.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer from another [thread on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same).

The first step would be to install tofrodos (an utility to convert files between DOS and Unix). In a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos
```

Then open a terminal in android project directory:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

The above command will go through the folders and change files to LF format.

Then do the following in your project directory:

```
git add -uv
```

This adds the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It help me to understand what the actual problem is!