# Error when trying to extract hyperledger artifacts

Tags: git-bash, hyperledger

i am using Windows 10 (64-bit) and i seem to have all the prerequisites installed.

However, while running the command `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/examples/e2e_cli/bootstrap.sh | bash` on Git-Bash, i will get the following error:

```
$ curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/examples/e2e_cli/bootstrap.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1205    0  1205    0     0    976      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--   988

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
bash: line 12: cd: release/mingw32_nt-10.0-wow-i686: No such file or directory
sh: download-dockerimages.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work on my Windows 10, with Git 2.13.

Try again, but with a simplify PATH first.
In a CMD, type:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\Git\2.13
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then type '`bash`', and in the bash session, try your `curl` command again.