# git display different techniques to see hidden characters

Tags: git, git-diff

I have executed `git diff.UserlogList .js`, but git is showing that I've deleted line and added a new one, the line that I have added is the same, how I can see invisible chars? Or there is another logic in git that I don't understand?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git status shows files as changed even though contents are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `--color-words` option to `git diff`. More info at [man git-diff](https://gitirc.eu/git-diff.html).

There are also config options to control the colouring of the diff output, useful for spotting small differences such as whitespace changes. See [man git-config](https://gitirc.eu/git-config.html), look for `color.diff.<slot>`.