# how to prevent "npm install" change package.json

Tags: node.js, git, npm, npm-install

I have a Maven project where I execute `npm install` in build with the `com.github.eirslett frontend-maven-plugin` plugin.

My problem is that after the build, git says me that the `package.json` has been changed, although when I check the diff (in IntelliJ) it says `Contents are identical`. If i run `stat package.json` I see that all timestamps of the file have been changed.

How can I avoid npm install changing the `package.json` file?

Solution: See answer from `James Monger`

Comment: It'll probably be a carriage return issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git status shows files as changed even though contents are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same)

Comment: Yes it could be. But how I stop npm from changing the package.json at all.

Comment: @Elio You can't do that easily

Comment: It's not a npm issue. You just need to configure GIT to not care

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `.gitattributes` file in your project root with the following contents:

```
package.json text eol=lf
package-lock.json text eol=lf
```

That will specify that `package.json` and `package-lock.json` should always use `LF` file endings.