# Git diff showing unchanged files

Tags: git

A repository I've been working and committing/pushing with for a while is showing unchanged files have been changed.

After adding/committing these files I can generate a patch which shows they have not been changed.  Why does git think these are changed?

```
 .../bar/index.js     |   0
 .../foo.txt          |   0
```

Comment: Do the files have special caracters? are you switching between different os (different line endings)?

Comment: I have not switched operating systems, I'm not sure if they have special characters.  Is there a way I can get them to show up on the diffs/patches?

Comment: You may want to take a look here: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/04/22/git-showing-file-as-modified-even-if-it-is-unchanged/ and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787937/git-status-shows-files-as-changed-even-though-contents-are-the-same

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove files saying "old mode 100755 new mode 100644" from unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257592/how-do-i-remove-files-saying-old-mode-100755-new-mode-100644-from-unstaged-cha)

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the file permissions.  I found the difference by looking through `git diff` and seeing this.

```
old mode 100755  
new mode 100644
```