# PhpStorm Git integrated vs commandline

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-status, integrated

Files committed via PhpStorm's integrated Git handling still show as modified when viewed with commandline  `git status`.   They still push successfully to the remote on GitLab.

Comment: Please include more details. What does `git diff` say on those files?

Answer (score 0):

With [Git 2.8+ (Q1 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204436/6309), you can use `git ls-files --eol -- a/file/still/modified` to check if the current change is related ot EOL (end of line character: `\n` vs. `\r\n`)

That way, you will know more about *why* those files are shown modified in your working tree (and displayed as modified in your IDE).