# command: 'git checkout -- filename' does not working

Tags: git

after using command: git checkout -- filename, git status still tell me the content has been changed, and I checked that file, it has one more line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if `git config core.autocrlf` is set to `true` or `native`.
That could trigger an automatic EOL (end-of-line) conversion.

A [`git ls-files --eol -- filename`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204436/6309) can also help checking if an attribute directive (if you have a `.gitattributes` in your repository) is applied.