# GIT conflict on a lot of files I didn't modified

Tags: git

My coworker modified a lot of files which I haven't touched at all.
But when I try to git pull now, a lot of conflicts appear in the files he touched, but I did not.
And the conflict is on the content of the whole file. It starts with:

```
<<<<<<HEAD
{content of the whole file}
=========
{content of the whole file}
>>>>>>>{commit code}
```

I want to accept his changes, but proceed with normal conflicts if we really both modified the files. 
Why does this happen and how to fix it ?

Comment: Something change to someone's line endings settings?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you and your co-worker are using different line endings. This can be the case if you're on different platforms (e.g. Windows vs Linux vs MacOS). See the following questions:

[Git marks entire file as conflicted when merging master into branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954958/git-marks-entire-file-as-conflicted-when-merging-master-into-branch)

[What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)

Comment: Or that git is set up to mess up with EOLs.

Comment: Yes, he is on Windows and I am on Mac.
I tried setting the line edngins git the git global config and etc. I've run a renormalize command, commited again, but sadly the result is the same. A conflict on the whole file. Should I do that on his computer too ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this the easy and safe way, stash your changes, then pull and finaly apply your stash again.
Any appearing problems should now be "real".

```
git stash
git fetch
git pull
git stash pop
```