# fatal error when commit using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, github, arduino, tortoisegit

While attempting to `Git Commit -> "master"` a `Arduino INO` file I get the error:

`TortoiseGit`  `fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in xxx.INO`

I had chosen 'Commit Line Endings as they are' as I was installing Git for Windows.

Any idea on this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an Arduino specific question. The only Arduino specific part is that Arduino's IDE does not use CRLF. Having said that you might want to consult ["What's the best CRLF handling strategy with git?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855862/2036917)

Once you read this, add a line to **.gitattributes** for your ino files to not use CRLF.

```
*.ino text eol=lf
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Udo.  Like a dancing dog.  It's amazing that it happens at all not how well it dances.

Comment: It looked like this was the right answer - but it was not.  I read though all the material on this problem and did install a .gitattributes file with *.ino text elo=lf but the results were the same.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, looks more like a tortoiseGit issue then. Did you check what the line endings actually are right now? Just to be sure what we have to go after.