# Rails 4 create LF files on Windows. I couldn't commit this in Git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, command-line-arguments, core.autocrlf

I created a new rails app.

```
rails new myfirstapp
```

It have created files with LF only.

I tried to init git repo.

```
git init
```

and after

```
git add .
```

I got this error:

```
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore
```

My git congfig:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
alias.co=checkout
alias.ci=commit
alias.st=status
alias.br=branch
alias.hist=log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
alias.type=cat-file -t
alias.dump=cat-file -p
core.quotepath=off
core.ignorecase=true
core.autocrlf=true
core.safecrlf=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
```

I am on Windows.
What do you think?

UPD:
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0

UPD:

I read all link on stackoverflow like this:

[Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)!

[What's the best CRLF handling strategy with git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-handling-strategy-with-git)!
I dont undestend why it's not working.

Comment: shouldn't it be `git init` not `git ini`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, since that's not where the error occurred I think we can assume that's a typo in the question.

Comment: @Chris - just helping the poster to make his question better :)

Answer (score 0):

You get that message because of

```
core.autocrlf=true
```

That's why you are getting...

```
...LF would be replaced by CRLF
```

Comment: For Windows users:

git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf true

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
rails new myfirstapp
git init
```

This is for saveing files as is.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input 
git add .
git commit -m"Bla bla bla"
```

This is for normal working and converting in windows format:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Delete all file and directories without .git

```
git checkout -f
```

This convert all files to CRLF on working tree.