# SourceTree thinks the whole file has changed when I change single lines

Tags: git, actionscript-3, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree for Mac which I'm using with my AS3 project do not track changes in class files. More accurately speaking, it treats them more like a single line of code rather than a sequence of lines. So, when I change something, version control shows that the whole file has changed. It doesn't happen in all AS3 projects, but in some of them, so I'm guessing it has something to do with project Git settings.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a line ending issue. What text editor are you using?

Comment: I was using Flash CC 2014/2015

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git + https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: Thanks for hints, everyone! I'll look deeper into the problem