# Git line endings in multi OS environment

Tags: linux, windows, git, line-endings

I installed Linux Mint on PC and then I cloned git repository from Bitbucket to work on it. After some changes I did commit in my PhpStorm ide. During this commit git fired me a dialog about line endings. There were two options. If I remember

1. create gitattribute file which handles line endings for project
2. set global handler for line endings via command like core.autocrlf true

I selected global option but as I see it made all the project files changed. Now I am not sure what happens and if I can push it to server. What happens if somebody pulls it on Windows? Will make a merge? How to solve it?

Comment: .gitattributes is now the recommended way to go... (because config is in the repository and shared by all on every OS)

Comment: So what should I do now? And what about binary files, cause as I am reading now it also about binary files. I am really confused what to do.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [git-config Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **core.autocrlf**
>
> Setting this variable to "true" is almost the same as setting the text attribute to "auto" on all files except that text files are not guaranteed to be normalized: files that contain CRLF in the repository will not be touched. Use this setting if you want to have CRLF line endings in your working directory even though the repository does not have normalized line endings. This variable can be set to input, in which case no output conversion is performed.

Having `core.autocrlf` set to `true` means that git will conditionally convert line endings to `CRLF` in your working directory and to `LF` in your repository.

Please see:  [What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)

Comment: But I am working in team where some people have Wins and I have Linux. This is not my repository where I want to have something. I need cooperate with other people. Now I would choose input. But  II dont know....