# GIT : disable eol check during comparison of local files with remote files

Tags: git

I have a common issue with Git : I am working on Linux , and my colleagues are working on Windows.

When I do a git status, git tells me all files in my workspace have been modified (I guess because of the eol)

I would like git to show me only the files that I have really changed in my workspace.

How can I do that?

I have tried  :

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

or changing .gitattributes file , but I can't get anything working.

Comment: Explicitly disabling the option that does what you ask isn't likely to work :).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git)

Comment: aside: `I guess because of the eol` - please do not guess, look what the diff is and put that in the question (verbatim. Do not paraphrase, show the output of `git diff`).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. i have found the issue : not related to eol. It was a matter of file rights. On my linux , rights seemed not to be the same as on git. I did git **config core.filemode false** and it works