# What rule is git using from .gitattributes to determine the file type and line ending?

Tags: git

I'm trying to track down what rule is being used for files in my repo when I have a .gitattributes file.  **Is there a git command that tells you what a given file's type (text vs binary) and line-ending are?**

To understand what I'm asking for, consider the following (truncated) `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.dll binary
*.exe binary

WinBin/* text eol=crlf
scripts/* text eol=lf
```

**How should the following files be treated and which rule should be used?**  Below is my guess

```
test1.bat => Should match *.bat text eol=crlf
WinBin\test1.bat => Should match WinBin/* text eol=crlf
WinBin\test2.exe=> Should match WinBin/* text eol=crlf (but I'd rather it were binary)
scripts\test1.bat => Should match scripts/* text eol=lf
```

There are lots of resources out there describing how git's end-of-line works and the various issues.  Below are some I've found

### Some useful links

- https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes - Git attributes documentation page.
- https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/cqgtgw/is_there_any_way_to_100_enforce_certain_line/ - Great write up describing why git end-of-line issues are difficult to track down.
- SO question [What's the best CRLF (carriage return, line feed) handling strategy with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-best-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-handling-strategy-with-git/10855862#10855862)

#### My configuration

I'm on windows using [Git for Windows (GfW)](https://gitforwindows.org/) and I've used git from git `bash.exe` as well as from Windows `cmd.exe`;  I also have [cygwin git](https://cygwin.com/index.html).

```
GitForWindows: git --version => git version 2.26.0.windows.1 (latest)
Cygwin Git: git --version => git version 2.8.3 (pretty out of date)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`git check-attr`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr) — Display gitattributes information.

> For every pathname, this command will list if each attribute is unspecified, set, or unset as a gitattribute on that pathname.

You probably need option `-a`:

```
git check-attr -a test1.bat WinBin\test1.bat WinBin\test2.bat scripts\test1.bat
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically, what happens is that the attributes handler is given a file name and a list of rules from all the various `.gitattributes` files (there can be more than one).  For each file name:

- The name implies some directory, e.g., when the name is `scripts/foo`,<sup>1</sup> the file is in a `scripts` directory, so the attributes file from that directory (`scripts/.gitattributes`) takes priority and the `.gitattributes` from the `src/` directory (`src/.gitattributes`) does not apply at all.
- Starting with the *lowest* priority file, Git applies each line to see if it matches.  If it *does* match, all the attributes on that line apply.  If an earlier line set an attribute, this later line overrides it.  Otherwise, the earlier-set attribute still applies.
- Git repeats this process for all applicable attribute files.  Since the higher priority ones apply *later*, their lines override.  The last lines of such files override earlier lines.

In this case, then, you had two applicable lines in the same `.gitattributes` file that would apply to `scripts/test1.bat`.  So for that file:

```
*.bat text eol=crlf
scripts/* text eol=lf
```

the first line matches and sets `eol=crlf`, then the later line matches and sets `text` and sets `eol=lf`.

The result is that the final attributes grouping for this particular file is: `text` (set), `eol=lf`.

You didn't try this as an example, but suppose you had a file named `scripts/a.exe`.  There's a line:

```
*.exe binary
```

along with the line:

```
scripts/* text eol=lf
```

so the combination here *appears to be* `binary` (set), `text` (set), and `eol=lf`.  However, `binary` is itself a *macro*.  You can define your own macros (though only in *some* attribute files).  In this case, the macro expands to `-diff -merge -text`.

Each `-` means *unset*.  So along with unsetting `diff` and `merge`, the first matching line did an *unset `text`* operation.  The second matching line, `scripts/*`, did a *set `text`* operation, which overrode the previous *unset `text`* operation.  The end result is that for this file, `text` is set, `diff` is unset, `merge` is unset, and `eol` is set-to-`lf`.

Note that *unset* is different from *unspecified*.  An *unspecified* attribute `foo` means that no line explicitly had `-foo` or `foo` or `foo=value` on it.<sup>2</sup>  Except for the predefined macros and the attribute names called out in the documentation, attribute names aren't really fixed in stone: future versions of Git might add new ones, and you can set or unset or set-to-a-value attribute names that you make up yourself, and Git won't say anything about them.  Writing:

```
* foo=bar
```

has no effect because nothing inside Git currently looks for a `foo` attribute, but if a future Git decided to use `foo` to mean something, it might suddenly start doing things.

It's pretty hard to deal with all of this, which is why `git check-attr` exists.  See [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61129738/1256452).

---

<sup>1</sup>Git turns all backslashes to forward ones internally.  You might want to favor the forward slash because `\b`, for instance, means *backspace* to some shell commands; `\t` means *tab*, `\r` means carriage-return, and so on.  If you're using sh or bash, the shell will do its own thing with them, so reserve them for the shell.  Do not use them in path names.  Use the forward slash—it's easier to type anyway!

<sup>2</sup>If some previous line has set, unset, or set-to-some-value some attribute `foo`, a *later* line can undo that with `!foo`.  This removes all settings and puts `foo` back into *unspecified* state.  This is entirely different from `-foo`, which puts foo into *unset* state.

(Not every attribute that has a meaning actually uses all these distinctions.)

Comment: Awesome answer/explanation.  Best wishes.