# How to fix wrong pylint warning in JupyterLab about CRLF line ending (or how to fix line ending if the warning should be true)?

Tags: jupyter-lab, pylint, jupyterlab-lsp

I use **pylint** for **JupyterLab** via **jupyterlab-lsp** on **Windows** and get warnings about the line ending format:

```
There is 'CRLF' while it should be 'LF'
```

[image]

I opened the notebook file in a text editor ensured that the line ending is LF.
I also tried to search for \r\n in the notebook and did not find wrong line endings.
The warning is still present.

I also tried to find a JupyterLab setting to change the line ending to LF. There does not seem to be a setting and LF (\n) seems to be the default.

=> The pylint warning seems to be a **false positive**, maybe related to the way/workflow pylint is applied by jupyterlab-lsp (issue when transformed from notebook to a script file? only a wild guess)?

=> How can I fix the check?

=> If the check really is fine: how can I fix the line endings inside the cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation [here](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/unexpected-line-ending-format.html), either the pylint configuration can help i.e.

```
[FORMAT]
expected-line-ending-format=LF
```

Or the link to the way to [deal with line ending using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170961/whats-the-strategy-for-handling-crlf-carriage-return-line-feed-with-git/10855862#10855862)

Comment: Pylint is already configured to expect LF. The warning shown in the screenshot says "There is 'CRLF' while it should be 'LF'. And the line ending in the text file seems to be fine.

Comment: It's very unlikely that pylint is wrong (it's not a particularly complex check), maybe try adding a ``.gitattributes`` and launching ``git add --renormalize .`` See https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/crlf-vs-lf-normalizing-line-endings-in-git/#verifying-line-endings-in-git-for-any-file